# If the following parameters don't match, will VPN still work?

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn

If the below fields don't match between two firewalls will VPN connectivity be compromised?
If not, which of the elements MUST be the same on both sides to ensure connectivity.  Keep in mind the first 4 are global settings, and the last (sla monitor) is a per connection configuration.

```
crypto ipsec df-bit clear-df outside
crypto ipsec security-association replay window-size 128
crypto ipsec fragmentation before-encryption outside
sysopt connection tcpmss 1387

sla monitor 1
 type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho x.x.x.x interface outside
 frequency 5
exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VPN will still work, but there may possibly be some problems when passing large packets.  The first 4 commands affect the maximum packet size and fragmentation.  Depending on the MTU of your Internet connection, this may or may not be an issue.

The SLA commands do not affect the VPN per se.   However, they may be used to affect routing or some other operation.  I can't tell with just the snippet you've provided.

Comment: Hey Ron, thanks - yeah the first 4 I was assuming were Amazon's desire to offload all the fragmentation to us instead of them if it's required.  Any other thoughts on that?  What symptoms could we see if these don't match what they have on their end?

Comment: Well - was waiting for a response to this comment for more clarification, but objectively the question was answered.  marking as such, thanks again for your feedback.